# is there no way to detect webview (chrome/android) with client side language?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, webview

I've figured out how to detect when my page is loaded on mobile in webview, but only for iOS with:

```
var standalone = window.navigator.standalone,
uerAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
safari = /safari/.test( userAgent ),
ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent );
```

I've researched and it seems like chrome/android has to be done on the server side - do anyone know whether it is possible with JS to detect whether website is opened within webview on chrome/android? For example when your website is opened up within Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom string as user-agent in your app's WebView.So if the user-agent is the custom string,you know that now it's in your app's WebView.

Android:

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("your agent");
```

iOS:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": "your agent"])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The app is Facebook, so I do not have access to the code in the app. Any other good ideas?